# How can I change tabs's side border color when it is active

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I cannot change  `material-ui` tabs side border color when it is active.
How can I change?

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

movie
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnF0V.jpg
img
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JLk6.jpg

[image: my css code here]

Comment: Please put code directly into your question text rather than in an image.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `outline` css property. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).

If you don't want the outline, do this: `outline: none` (usually on the `:focus` state). But when you do that, you want to make sure that you're setting it with something else, especially for accessibility purposes.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to select that as your answer. It may be of help to others. Also, in case of next time, try to put your code directly in your question, as @RyanCogswell has mentioned